# Check if any of multiple values returned from query exist in a list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a filter on my web page adn I have a complex issue that I don't know how to resolve.

In my main table i have multiple values of books and each row is to specify if that book has or not an attribute:

| book | attr | isPresent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book1 | Attr1 | 1 |
| Book1 | Attr2 | 0 |
| Book1 | Attr3 | 1 |
| Book2 | Attr1 | 0 |
| Book2 | Attr2 | 0 |
| Book2 | Attr3 | 1 |
| Book3 | Attr1 | 1 |
| Book3 | Attr2 | 1 |
| Book3 | Attr3 | 1 |

In this table for example.. If I select on the filter (Attr1 and Attr2) I want to retrieve all Books that have any of those Attr selected, that means Book1 and Book3 in the example.

In my query if I do these:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE isPresent = 1 && attr IN (Attr1, Attr2)
```

I will get all books because the Book2 has an Attr1 and Attr2 and a Attr3 with `isPresent = 1` so it's on the result. But I want to discard this case.

Comment: This should not return Book2. The condition is applied row-wise and none of the Book2 rows satisfies the condition.

Comment: You only want to return the books and there is an entry for every attribute in the table? Then simply `select book from books where attr in ('Attr1', 'Attr3') group by book having min(ispresent) = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a conditional aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE book IN (
    SELECT book
    FROM books
    WHERE attr IN ('Attr1', 'Attr2')
    GROUP BY book
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN attr = 'Attr1' AND isPresent = 1 THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
           MAX(CASE WHEN attr = 'Attr2' AND isPresent = 1 THEN 1 END) = 1
);
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT attr) = 2` is redundant as it is covered by the other two `HAVING` filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` and correlated sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   table_name x
               WHERE  isPresent = 1
               AND    attr = 'Attr1'
               AND    x.book = t.book )
AND    EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   table_name x
               WHERE  isPresent = 1
               AND    attr = 'Attr2'
               AND    x.book = t.book )
```

or using conditional aggregation and analytic functions (which is more efficient, as it would only read the table once, but slightly more to type):

```sql
SELECT book,
       attr,
       isPresent
FROM   (
  SELECT book,
         attr,
         isPresent,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN attr='Attr1' AND isPresent=1 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY book) AS has_attr1,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN attr='Attr2' AND isPresent=1 THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY book) AS has_attr2
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  has_attr1 > 0
AND    has_attr2 > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (book, attr, isPresent) AS
SELECT 'Book1', 'Attr1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book1', 'Attr2', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book1', 'Attr3', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book2', 'Attr1', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book2', 'Attr2', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book2', 'Attr3', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book3', 'Attr1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book3', 'Attr2', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Book3', 'Attr3', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| BOOK | ATTR | ISPRESENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book3 | Attr1 | 1 |
| Book3 | Attr2 | 1 |
| Book3 | Attr3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C0JldIkD)

Answer (score 0):

```
select book from table_name
where (attr, isPresent) in (
 ('Attr1', 1), ('Attr2',1)
)
group by book ;
```

and

```
select book from table_name
where (attr, isPresent) in (
 ('Attr1', 1), ('Attr2',1)
)
group by book having (count(*) = 2) 
;
```

to have the ones having both.